# pattern matching in sudoers file using tab space in pattern

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I need to write a shell script to check the entry is there or not in /etc/sudoers file

this is the pattern i need to check 
**nimbus      ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL**

in this pattern word to word tab space is there

how to find the pattern exist in file /etc/sudoers or not using linux shell script from root user only

```
  SomeString='nimbus      ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL'
File=sudoers
echo $File
echo -e $SomeString

if grep -q $SomeString "$File"; then
   echo "line found"
else
   echo "line not found"
fi
```

error i got grep: ALL=(ALL): No such file or directory grep: NOPASSWD:ALL: No such file or directory

please help me in this regard

thanks 
sagar

Comment: Did you make an attempt? How did you fail doing it?

Comment: SomeString='nimbus      ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL'
File=sudoers
echo $File
echo -e $SomeString

if grep -q $SomeString "$File"; then
   echo "line found"
else
   echo "line not found"
fi
i am getting following error                                                                              grep: ALL=(ALL): No such file or directory
grep: NOPASSWD:ALL: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your script is, you are not escaping(`\`) the meta-characters(`(` and `)` in this case) for `grep` to identify them as they have a special meaning.

Also quoting variables prevents word splitting and glob expansion, and prevents the script from breaking when input contains spaces, line feeds, glob characters and such.

The modified version of your script should be like

```
#!/bin/bash

SomeString='nimbus      ALL=\(ALL\)       NOPASSWD:ALL'      # Notice the '\' of the characters
File=sudoers
echo "$File"
echo -e "$SomeString"

if grep -qE "$SomeString" "$File"; then
    echo "line found"
else
    echo "line not found"
fi
```

With this change your script works.

```
$ cat sudoers
nimbus      ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD:ALL
foo
bar

foobar

$ ./script.sh
sudoers
nimbus      ALL=\(ALL\)       NOPASSWD:ALL
line found
```

Read more about [grep-regular-expressions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-grep-regular-expressions-to-search-for-text-patterns-in-linux)

Comment: suppose my file is like this  root ALL=(ALL) ALL and now i want to find for nimbus ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL . if found no need to do anything. if not found need to add the nimbus line after root line . what to do